# wpf datagrid: write value in textbox column

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridtextcolumn

I have a Datagrid with some columns. It is binded to a list of objects. 
One of the column is a text column: I need it as a "validation" column, infact I want that, for each row, the value of this cell is "OK" or "NOT OK", based on values present in other cells. I don't know how to write a string into a certain cell into the Datagrid.
Any suggestion?

EDIT:
following the class that describes the objects of DataGrid

```
public class BracketProperty
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int index { get; set; }
    public BracketType type { get; set;}
    public List<BracketPoint> bracketPointsList;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public String isPointSelectionEnded { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT2: 
someone tells me that this line of code is not good

```
this.BracketsDataGrid.ItemsSource = this.currentPropertyToShow.sides[this.sideIndex - 1].brackets;
```

where `brackets` is defined as

```
 public ObservableCollection<BracketProperty> brackets;
```

because is not a binding...how can I change it to be a binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a data type class that has a `public` property for each column in the `DataGrid`. You should implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface in this class.

Then you can have a property which you could update in a `PropertyChanged` handler:

```
private void YourDataType_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Property1 == "SomeValue" && Property2 > 0) ValidationProperty = "OK";
    else ValidationProperty = "NOT OK"; // Add your own condition above of course
}
```

In the constructor:

```
PropertyChanged += YourDataType_PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: I already have a data type class with public property for each column of DataGrid (I've added it in my question above). The problem is that, if I implement the INotifyPropertyChanged in that class, it raises an exception at startup, because of loop on field isPointSelectionEnded. How do I implement the interface in proper way? Notice that the I do the work between different classes.

Comment: In my answer, I provided you with a link to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` page at MSDN (2nd line)... click it and follow the help on that page.

Comment: If I implement the INotifyPropertyChanged, and in setter change the value to "Not ok", the value changes but the grid is not automatically upadated...and I see the old value...is it good to do the refresh of items? I ask it because randomly it raises an exception like "Refresh is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction"

Comment: When you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface correctly, your `public` properties should call the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event after they are set. This will 'refresh' that field in the UI. Therefore set the value using the `public` property to ensure that the event is called.

Comment: I've done it but the UI does not refresh the value...someone tells me that can be a problem of binding...I update code in the question about it

Answer (score 0):

Use Value Converters

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> EmpList { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        EmpList = new ObservableCollection<Employee> { 
            new Employee(1, "a"), 
            new Employee(2, "b"), 
            new Employee(3, "c") };
    }
}

public class NumValueConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int v = int.Parse(value.ToString());
        if (v < 3) 
            return "YES";
        else 
            return "NO";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Employee(int s, string n)
    {
        Salary = s;
        Name = n;
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="garbagestack.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:garbagestack"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <cv:NumValueConverter x:Key="cv1"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="12,99,12,12" Name="dg1" ItemsSource="{Binding EmpList}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="NewValue" Binding="{Binding Salary}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="NewValue" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="NewValue" Binding="{Binding Salary,Converter={StaticResource cv1}}">

                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Question is based on values in other columns

Answer (score 0):

I need to answer to question on my own. I have not implemented any INotifyPropertyChanged interface or Converter...the only code added, after setting the value of the variable for control, is the following:

```
 this.DataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

and text is correctly shown in the grid...

However, it is better to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged, following the MVVM pattern rules.